# compare and update spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Please I need some help with excel spreadsheet here. I have two worksheets, one holding the old records and the other holding the current record. What I wish to do is to develop a vba code associated with a command button,find sample below, so that when the button is clicked on, values in the old record will automatically be updated based on the values from the new record. For clarity, here is a snapshot of the worksheets.

Sheet1 contain the old records, which is live and can be seen by over 100 users.
sheet2 contain the new records, which is being updated from various sources and any of the field/coln can be changed by the field users.

Field1 in both sheets hold the primary control field. So what I want to do is take each value of field1 in sheet2 and then search it in field1 of sheet1, if the value exist, I want to compare all the corresponding records so that any difference is copied from sheet2 to sheet1 for all the fields. If the value is not in sheet1 at all, I want to copy all the value and all associated records in sheet2 to sheet1. Invariably, I want to keep updating sheet1 based on the new update in sheet2.

I hope I made myself clear enough. Please note that the sample table is just a simplified version as I have 75 fields/coln and over 70,000 records in the tables.

Thanks for your anticipated help and support in accomplishing this.

```
**SHEET1**
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4
Radms Street    781772  2   76
Mapre Street    781772  31  76
Catapilar Av    781727  1   90
Aveb Park   781727  56  91

**SHEET2**
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4
Aveb Park   781727  56  91
Radms Street    781770  2   76
Solution Way    761111  67  1
Aknyt Road  781720  91  90
Mapre Street    781772  31  76
weedred Park    781781  23  61
Raven Road  781781  76  61
Catapilar Av    781720  21  76
```

Comment: Please use code blocks to properly format your samples of worksheets' data

Comment: @tumchaaditya yes. You can edit it for formatting as well.

Comment: User, what have you tried so far? Have you looked into a vlookup, but there are too many records for it to calculate quickly enough? Do you want to use a macro? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Raystafarian: Oh yes I could have. But I was trying to educate the OP who is clearly a new joinee on posting questions properly..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am currently managing this with a Vlookup, but what I need now is a Macro to manage the process as the data will continue to grow within the next six months.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA will work, just adjust the ranges to your cells so it doesn't run indefinitely. Also adjust the for loop of `i` to reflect how many fields you have.

This VBA assumes the values are in the same order in both sheets and doesn't replace blanks, but also **doesn't compare values**.

```
Sub comparesheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As Range
Dim strFind As String
Dim rFound As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each c In Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:A")
strFind = c.Value

    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=strFind, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            For i = 1 To 4
                If rFound.Offset(, i) <> "" Then
                    c.Offset(, i) = rFound.Offset(, i)
                End If
            Next i

        End If
    End With

Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```